# How do I loop through all dynamically created radiobuttons and how do I identify them?

Tags: android

I've got an app that dynamically adds radiobuttons from json data. I don't really know how to find out which ones are selected though. There are the `radioButton.isSelected()` and the `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` but since it's dynamically created I cannot use names for all the objects.

Is there a way to add them to a group upon creation and cycle through all of them later? I've got multiple radiogroups and not all of them but most are supposed to be checked.

I'm using api lvl 7 (2.1) and I'm fairly new to this. Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<RadioButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
//create your new button and add it here.
radioButtons.add(radioButton);
```

Then to iterate through the list if you need to retrieve each button, use a for loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<radioButtons.size();i++){
    RadioButton button = radioButtons.get(i);
    //do what you need with the button
}
```

And if you need each RadioButton to have certain data, then you could do:

```
radioButton.setTag("tag");
```

and then when you are iterating through the loop, you can do `button.getTag();`

Or if you just want to get the selected one:

```
RadioButton button = (RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

I think I covered everything from your question and maybe more. Let me know if I missed anything or need to give any additional explanation.

Comment: this along with http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13741 (how to make global variables) solved it. Thanks alot!